# Error when trying to load custom Client Editor

Tags: javascript, dojo, episerver, episerver-7

I've followed the steps in [this article](http://world.episerver.com/Blogs/Linus-Ekstrom/Dates/2012/7/Creating-a-custom-editor-for-a-property/) to create a basic custom editor but I'm getting a 404 error when trying to enter Forms Edit mode from

> /EPiServer/CMS/1.0.456/ClientResources/dtk/app/editors/EmailTextbox.js

The document linked article states that EPiServer automatically adds a mapping from /ClinetResources/Scripts to the `app` namespace. I took a punt and added a module.config to the root of my site, like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<module>
    <assemblies>
        <!-- This adds the Alloy template assembly to the "default module" -->
        <add assembly="PropertyTest" />
    </assemblies>

    <dojoModules>
        <!-- Add a mapping from alloy to ~/ClientResources/Scripts to the dojo loader configuration -->
        <add name="app" path="Scripts" />
    </dojoModules>
</module>
```

This fixed the 404 but now I get a type error in the console when I try to enter forms mode

> TypeError {}                                   dojo.js:15
>   (anonymous function)                    dojo.js:15
>   dojo.Deferred.reject.errback         dojo.js:15
>   _174                                              dojo.js:15
>   dojo.Deferred._171.then.then       dojo.js:15
>   dojo.Deferred.when.dojo.when      dojo.js:15
>   dojo.declare._createInternal          widgets.js:2
>   (anonymous function)                    widgets.js:2
>   _388                                              dojo.js:15
>   map                                               dojo.js:15
>   dojo.declare._createWidgets        widgets.js:2
>   (anonymous function)                   widgets.js:2
>   _388                                             dojo.js:15
>   _c6                                                dojo.js:15
>   _36                                                dojo.js:15
>   _7a                           dojo.js:15
>   _ee                           dojo.js:15
>   req.injectUrl._109                           dojo.js:15

**Why is this erroring?**

The source of my JS file is as per the linked article but I've included below for completeness.

```
define([
    // Inherited mixins
    "dojo",
    "dojo/_base/declare",
    "dijit/_Widget",
    "dijit/_TemplatedMixin"
], function (
    dojo,
    declare,
    _Widget,
    _TemplatedMixin) {

    declare("app.editors.EmailTextbox", [_Widget, _TemplatedMixin], {

        // templateString: [protected] String  
        //    A string that represents the default widget template.  
        templateString: '<div> \
                          <input type="email" data-dojo-attach-point="email" data-dojo-attach-event="onchange:_onChange" /> \
                         </div>',

        postCreate: function () {
            // summary:  
            //    Set the value to the textbox after the DOM fragment is created.  
            // tags:  
            //    protected  

            this.set('value', this.value);

            if (this.intermediateChanges) {
                this.connect(this.email, 'onkeydown', this._onIntermediateChange);
                this.connect(this.email, 'onkeyup', this._onIntermediateChange);
            }
        },

        focus: function () {
            // summary:  
            //    Put focus on this widget.  
            // tags:  
            //    public  

            dijit.focus(this.email);
        },

        isValid: function () {
            // summary:  
            //    Indicates whether the current value is valid.  
            // tags:  
            //    public  

            var emailRegex = '[a-zA-Z0-9_.-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+.[a-zA-Z0-9-.]+';
            if (!this.required) {
                emailRegex = '(' + emailRegex + ')?';
            }
            var regex = new RegExp('^' + emailRegex + '$');
            return regex.test(this.value);
        },

        onChange: function (value) {
            // summary:   
            //    Called when the value in the widget changes.   
            // tags:   
            //    public callback   
        },

        _onIntermediateChange: function (event) {
            // summary:   
            //    Handles the textbox key press events event and populates this to the onChange method.   
            // tags:   
            //    private   

            if (this.intermediateChanges) {
                this._set('value', event.target.value);
                this.onChange(this.value);
            }
        },

        _onChange: function (event) {
            // summary:   
            //    Handles the textbox change event and populates this to the onChange method.   
            // tags:   
            //    private   

            this._set('value', event.target.value);
            this.onChange(this.value);
        },

        _setValueAttr: function (value) {
            // summary:   
            //    Sets the value of the widget to "value" and updates the value displayed in the textbox.   
            // tags:   
            //    private   

            this._set('value', value);
            this.email.value = this.value || '';
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you've gotten your script to load properly then it's a good idea to deploy the debug versions of the script files. Head over to [Debugging EPiServer CMS client side files](http://world.episerver.com/Download/Items/EPiServer-CMS/EPiServer-7---CMS/EPiServer-CMS-Debugging-of-Client-Side-Files/) for the download and instructions on how to deploy them.

With the compressed and minified versions it's very hard to figure out what's going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Are you aware that you can just use the `RegularExpression` attribute if you want email validation ?

```
[RegularExpression(EPiServer.Framework.Validator.EmailRegexString)]  
public virtual string Email { get; set; }
```

Comment: Hi @AlexB. The EmailTextBox is the example editor plugin from EPiServer. I was using it to illustrate the JavaScript issue loading editor plugins, not as a genuine *how do I...*

Answer (score 0):

If this occurs on a development box the solution is to disable the Broswer Link in Visual Studio.

[image]

http://www.herlitz.nu/2016/09/19/cant-load-the-episerver-edit-gui-in-development-environment/